# symbolic link to /usr/local/bin not running the program unless logged in as su

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I'm trying to get eclipse 3.8 installed on Ubuntu 10.04.
I've put the extracted files on:

```
/opt
```

I put a symbolic link in:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

ls -s /usr/local/bin:

```
eclipse -> /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

My path has /usr/local/bin in it...the permissions for the sym link are 777.

I also did as su:

```
chmod 755 /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

When I try to run eclipse as root, it works ( at least it tries, getting java error ).
Trying as regular user just gives me the prompt that I need to install eclipse-platform from the repo.

Comment: I changed the permission on the /opt/eclipse dir from 754 to 755 which now gives a different error when trying to start eclipse as regular user: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Eclipse:eclipse
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library.

The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library.

Comment: It appears there's an environment variable and I'm working on this via ssh without X11 working.

Comment: I think I solved my issue by setting the permissions on the eclipse parent and the env variable which tells eclipse where the it's root dir is. I can't confirm until I try locally. Thank JMG for the edits.

Comment: Remember to post your solution as an answer and accepted if you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think it is in your $PATH? Try running `echo $PATH`, do you see `/usr/local/bin`?

If you are running this through an `ssh` session my guess is that you have added `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` in your `~/.bahsrc` and that is not read when you `ssh` into a machine. Try adding this to your `~/.profile` instead:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: It seems I might have solved my problem as noted in my comments to my question. I'll check it out in person first. I did echo $PATH originally. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @wbg great! Do remember to post it as an answer if you've found it. Also, I just realized I'd made a mistake in my answer. It is `~/.bashrc` that is not read when you `ssh` and `~/.profile` that is. My guess is that you were setting your PATH in `~/.bashrc` and that's why it wasn't working. This won't be the case if you're opening a terminal locally though.